# How to map a UUID directly to both a device name (e.g. /dev/sda1) AND a mount point (e.g. /mnt/home2)?

Tags: hard-drive, mount, fstab, mappeddrive, block-device

I know how to map `/etc/fstab` to the mount point with the device name:

```
/dev/sdb1        /mnt/home2      ext4    usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0        0       0
```

This practice is however highly flawed as it is randomized and can change on reboots, especially when adding and removing disks. Instead, use UUID:

```
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx       /mnt/home2      ext4    usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0        0       0
```

The problem is that I need `/dev/sda1` to remain `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` to remain `/dev/sdb1` (...etc with many drives) throughout reboots and changing and removing of disks.

Therefore, how can I retain BOTH the device name such as `/dev/sda1` AND the mount point such as `/mnt/home2` which will never be lost when adding, removing disks or on reboots?

Can both be added via fstab? If not, how to do it?

Comment: "The problem is that I need /dev/sda1 to remain /dev/sda1"  Why? Non-persistent devices do not have consistency across adding hardware and bus rescans.

Comment: Because I want to, there are reasons but my request is reason enough.

Answer (score 0):

Or, label file systems and mount those volumes by `LABEL=`. Does not uniquely identify an instance of a file system, only its name. Which may be a desired feature, if UUID is not known.

---

Consider LVM for logical volume names independent of any hardware path, LUN ID, or file system ID.

On Linux, you can create file systems on and mount logical volumes with their `/dev/vg/lv` devices.  The advantage over UUID is that the file system can be reformatted or ID changed, but the same LV remains.

Comment: I meant to use it using the existing filesystem, not to create LVMs.

Comment: Then use a file system UUID or LABEL (I forgot label). /dev/sdb1  is a non-persistent device name, Red Hat calls it such in their documentation.

Comment: You literally completely ignored my question. The question was how to KEEP sda1, sdb1, etc

Comment: I do not have a solution that keeps the non-persistent block device names from moving around on hardware changes.